# Getting Unique Data from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting some duplicate rows from this query but able to understand how to get the data for unique SerialNumber(SerialNr).

> I need to get Unique `SerialNumber` with latest `someDate`

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @myDate datetime ;
SELECT @myDate = someDate FROM X ORDER BY someDate DESC;
SELECT
    d.someID,
    sd.Id,
    d.SerialNr as SerialNumber,
    convert(varchar(25), a.someDate, 121) as someDate
FROM A d WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN B sd ON d.myName = sd.myName
    INNER JOIN C a ON sd.AuditID = a.AuditID
WHERE a.someDate > @myDate 
GROUP BY d.someID, sd.Id, d.SerialNr, a.someDate
```

> On Running above this query I got this result but I need data Unique `SerialNUmber`

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
someID  | Id         | SerialNumber    | someDate
----------------------------------------------------------------
1086273 | 1811804430 | CNRXY35780      | 2020-01-30 22:11:07.607
1086273 | 1812119814 | CNRXY35780      | 2020-01-30 22:11:07.607
1086274 | 1811804766 | VNB3R56530      | 2020-01-30 22:11:07.607
1086276 | 1811804641 | U64968D8N889217 | 2020-01-30 22:11:07.607
1086276 | 1812119826 | U64968D8N889217 | 2020-01-30 22:11:07.607
```

I tried this but got error

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
;with ABC
(
    DECLARE @myDate datetime ;
    select @myDate = someDate from X order by someDate desc;
    SELECT top 1000 
        d.someID,
        sd.Id,
        d.SerialNr as SerialNumber,
        convert(varchar(25), a.someDate, 121) as someDate,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY d.DeviceId,d.SerialNr ORDER BY a.someDate desc) RID
    FROM A d
         INNER JOIN B sd ON d.someID = sd.someID
         INNER JOIN C a ON sd.AuditID = a.AuditID
    WHERE a.someDate > @myDate AND RID = 1
)
    select * from ABC
    where RID = 1
    GROUP BY d.DeviceId,sd.Id,d.SerialNr,a.someDate
```

> Here is the error :

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I tried this also

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @AuditDate datetime;
select @AuditDate = AuditDate from atr_usageSync order by AuditDate desc;
;with ABC AS
(
    SELECT top 1000 
        d.DeviceId,
        sd.Id,
        d.SerialNr as SerialNumber,
        convert(varchar(25), a.AuditDate, 121) as AuditDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeviceId,d.SerialNr ORDER BY a.AuditDate desc) RID
    FROM Device d
         INNER JOIN SuppliesData sd ON d.DeviceId = sd.DeviceId
         INNER JOIN Audit a ON sd.AuditID = a.AuditID
    WHERE a.AuditDate > @AuditDate
)
    select * from ABC
    where RID = 1
    GROUP BY DeviceId,Id,SerialNumber,AuditDate
```

> And this time I got this error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'ABC.RID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trials I got the correct query.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @myDate datetime;
select @myDate = someDate from X order by someDate desc;
;with CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        distinct  top 1000 d.SerialNr as SerialNumber, d.someId,
        sd.Id,
        convert(varchar(25), a.someDate, 121) as someDate,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY d.someId,d.SerialNr ORDER BY a.someDate desc) RID
    FROM A d
         INNER JOIN B sd ON d.someId = sd.someId
         INNER JOIN C a ON sd.AuditID = a.AuditID
    WHERE a.someDate > @myDate
)
    select top 10 * from CTE
    where RID = 1
    GROUP BY someId, Id, SerialNumber, someDate, RID
```

this gives me the correct Output but the query is slower any way to optimize the query

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare your variable outside of CTE.
2. `select @myDate = someDate from X order by someDate desc; -- Should be outside cte , below declare -- @myDate will store only one result here.`
3. AS was missing.

Either try :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @myDate datetime ;
select @myDate = someDate from X order by someDate desc;
;with ABC AS
(


    SELECT top 1000 
        d.someID,
        sd.Id,
        d.SerialNr as SerialNumber,
        convert(varchar(25), a.someDate, 121) as someDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeviceId,d.SerialNr ORDER BY a.someDate desc) RID
    FROM A d
         INNER JOIN B sd ON d.someID = sd.someID
         INNER JOIN C a ON sd.AuditID = a.AuditID
    WHERE a.someDate > @myDate AND RID = 1
)
    select * from ABC
    where RID = 1
    GROUP BY  d.someID,sd.Id,d.SerialNumber,a.someDate
```

OR

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @myDate datetime ;
    ;with ABC AS
    (


        SELECT top 1000 
            d.someID,
            sd.Id,
            d.SerialNr as SerialNumber,
            convert(varchar(25), a.someDate, 121) as someDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeviceId,d.SerialNr ORDER BY a.someDate desc) RID
        FROM A d
             INNER JOIN B sd ON d.someID = sd.someID
             INNER JOIN C a ON sd.AuditID = a.AuditID
        WHERE a.someDate > @myDate AND RID = 1
    )
        select * from ABC
        where RID = 1
        GROUP BY  d.someID,sd.Id,d.SerialNumber,a.someDate
```

And Pass some date to @myDate.

Comment: I tried this but getting the same error : ```Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'.```

Comment: 'AS' was missing here =>  ;with ABC AS .

Comment: In your question you were getting two errors  one was for 'Declare' which was inside cte (Error Line 4) and other was missing 'AS' keyword (Error Line 19).

Comment: I added `AS` in my query but still its giving error.

Comment: ```Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'.```. these are the errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207343/discussion-between-cedverd-and-pankaj-dwivedi).

Answer (score 0):

- You should move `DECLARE @myDate datetime ;` outside the CTE then assign it like below
- Your [syntax `CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is missing `AS` keyword

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @myDate datetime ;
    select top 1 @myDate = someDate from X order by someDate desc;

    ;with ABC AS
    (
        SELECT top 1000 
            d.someID,
            sd.Id,
            d.SerialNr as SerialNumber,
            convert(varchar(25), a.someDate, 121) as someDate,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY d.DeviceId,d.SerialNr ORDER BY a.someDate desc) RID
        FROM A d
             INNER JOIN B sd ON d.someID = sd.someID
             INNER JOIN C a ON sd.AuditID = a.AuditID
        WHERE a.someDate > @myDate AND RID = 1
    )
        select * from ABC
        where RID = 1
        GROUP BY d.DeviceId,sd.Id,d.SerialNr,a.someDate
```

Comment: NO I'm still getting the error ```Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ')'.``` Same Error as we were getting earlier

Comment: Your [syntax `CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is missing `AS` keyword

Answer (score 0):

The errors are caused by:

1. The typo on this line:

   `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY`

Should be:

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY`

2. And of course the declare statement along with the assignment select statement

`select @myDate = someDate from X order by someDate desc;`

should be positioned outside the CTE (also remove the space after the datetime data type as well as one of the ; characters (either the one before the CTE or the one after the previous statement).

Comment: ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY...) without space will also work.